# How to allocate an array of channels

Tags: arrays, go, channel

How to create an *array of channels*?

**For example:** replace the following five lines with an array of channels, with a size of 5:

```
var c0 chan int = make(chan int);
var c1 chan int = make(chan int);
var c2 chan int = make(chan int);
var c3 chan int = make(chan int);
var c4 chan int = make(chan int);
```

Answer (score 78):

The statement `var chans [5]chan int` would allocate an array of size 5, but all the channels would be `nil`.

One way would be to use a slice literal:

```
var chans = []chan int {
   make(chan int),
   make(chan int),
   make(chan int),
   make(chan int),
   make(chan int),
}
```

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you would have to iterate over it and initialize each element:

```
var chans [5]chan int
for i := range chans {
   chans[i] = make(chan int)
}
```

Comment: Why is your solution better than Chickencha's succinct and idiomatic `chans := make([]chan int, 5)`?

Comment: If the channels are not explicitly allocated with `make(chan int)`, they will default to `nil`.

Comment: This isn't a terrible option if you know in advance the number of channels you require.

Answer (score 2):

```
c := make(map[int]chan int)
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    c[i] = make(chan int)
}
for _,v := range c {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

You can create like that, use slice and channel

Answer (score 0):

Example for `[]chan[]string`. it can be extended for all type of cases.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var ch [4]chan []string
    for i := range ch {
        ch[i] = make(chan []string, 1)
    }

    ch1 := []string{"this", "that", "who"}

    ch2 := []string{"one", "two", "three"}

    ch3 := []string{"four", "five", "six"}

    ch4 := []string{"seven", "eight", "nine"}

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(1)
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        switch i {
        case 0:
            ch[i] <- ch1
        case 1:
            ch[i] <- ch2
        case 2:
            ch[i] <- ch3
        case 3:
            ch[i] <- ch4
        default:
        }
    }
    wg.Done()

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-ch[i])

    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If variable length array, initialize with for loop after `make([]chan int, N)`.

```
c := make([]chan int, 5) // [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil] (doesn't initialize yet)
for i := 0; i < len(c); i++ {
    c[i] = make(chan int)
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I think you can use buffered channels in this case.

Channels can be buffered. Provide the buffer length as the second argument to make to initialize a buffered channel:

```
ch := make(chan int, 5)
```

Sends to a buffered channel block only when the buffer is full. Receives block when the buffer is empty.

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3

Comment: An array can be filled in your order, an buffered channel is just something different