# How to pass array of channels

Tags: go

I am trying to pass a array of channels to the method "     func Data(channel chan<- []Book)" , however I encouter an error which states ( channel[0] (type chan<- []Book does not support indexing)") I understand what it means, but isn't there a way to pass an the array ? If so what alternatives do I have

```
     func Data(channel chan<- []Book) {
            var data EData
            data = ReadJSONFile("Data.json")

            go Writer(data.BookStores[0].Central, channel[0]) // at this 
          // place I get "invalid operation:  channel[0] (type chan<- []Book 
          // does not support indexing)"
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allocate an array of channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893004/how-to-allocate-an-array-of-channels)

Answer (score 2):

The proper type to pass a slice of channels of Book elements is:

```
[]chan<- Book
```

The code in your original question is for a channel of Book slices.

Answer (score 1):

`chan<- []Book` needs to become `[]chan<- Book`.  `[]` modifies the type after it in go, so if you want an array of channels, put it before `chan`.

```
func Data(channel []chan<- Book) {
    var data EData
    data = ReadJSONFile("Data.json")

    go Writer(data.BookStores[0].Central, channel[0])
    // ...
}
```

Test: https://play.golang.org/p/sQt3VawvhoI